# Pass some positional parameters to subcommand in CMD

Tags: cmd, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I have a CMD script that receives some parameters. It is called like this:

```
C:\myscript -A value -B value -C value -D -E -F value path1 path2 path3
```

It may receive several option-type parameters (not always the same number, may be none; some with argument, some without) and several path-type parameters (not always the same number, but always at least one). It is not an option to change that, because it is called by a program I can not control.

myscript must extract the path-type parameters only and pass them to one of its subcommands, like this:

```
@echo off
rem this is C:\myscript
C:\otherscript path1 path2 path3
```

I can not use numbered positional parameters like %1 %2 or %3 because I do not know in advance how many option-type parameters will there be, nor how many path-type options will there be.

Comment: Actual examples of the type of path will help.  Relative, UNC, explicit paths - it all matters.

Comment: Any path is valid. Only known for sure is that they all come after all options.

Comment: Then search for a \ in the parameter.

Comment: @foxidrive does not work: I said it can be anything, even a relative path with no backslashes on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grokking a while with this issue, and thanks to some insight from Torqane's answer, I've developed a script that works:

```
SET SAVEPATH=

:loop
SET var1=%1
SET VAR1NOQUOTE=%~1
SET VAR1FIRST=%VAR1NOQUOTE:~0,1%

if "%VAR1NOQUOTE%"=="" goto continue

rem test known no-argument options
if "%VAR1NOQUOTE%"="-A" goto shift1
if "%VAR1NOQUOTE%"="-B" goto shift1
rem etc... as many as needed

rem test options with arguments
if "%VAR1FIRST%"="-" goto shift2

rem if not an aption, it is a path
SET SAVEPATH=%SAVEPATH% %VAR1%
shift
goto loop

:shift1
shift
goto loop

:shift2
shift
shift
goto loop

:continue
C:\otherscript %SAVEPATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

With the additional benefit that the paths can show up anywhere in the command line, not just at the end.  Assumption is per your example, each option and its immediately following parameter are being ignored, and anything that shows up without an option preceding is a path you want to use in the call.

```
@echo off
rem this is C:\myscript too :)
rem do this so it's repeatable, or use setlocal/endlocal

set parmlist=

:loop
set parm=%1
if '%parm:~0,1%'=='-' goto option
set parmlist=%parmlist% %parm%
shift
if '%1'=='' goto done
goto loop

:option
shift
if '%1'=='' goto done
set parm=%1
if not '%parm:~0,1%'=='-' shift
if not '%1'=='' goto loop

:done
c:\otherscript %parmlist%
```

Tested with this command line:

```
myscript -a fred -b wilma firstpath -c -d barney secondpath thirdpath
```

result:

```
c:\otherscript  firstpath secondpath thirdpath
```

(yeah there's an extra space there but it's easier to read not to mash `otherscript` and `%parmlist%` right together)

Comment: I like it, but it does not help in the case in which you have a non-argument option like -E above followed by a path. Anyway it gives me thoughts.

Comment: Okay.  I don't really like the goto stuff but it works as modified above.  Nesting the conditions was buggy but the edited answer should do what you're looking for now.

Comment: Does not work for myscript.bat -a fred -b wilma firstpath -c secondpath -d barney thirdpath

Comment: You are giving -c an argument of secondpath and -d an argument of barney, so the only remaining parameters that are not absorbed by an -option are firstpath and thirdpath.  There's nothing wrong with the code; you're just absorbing secondpath as what you refer to in the OP as a Value parameter due to your use of it after -c.

Comment: I am not giving secondpath as an argument of -c. The question is explicit in that there are options with arguments (A, B, C, F in the question) and options without (D, E in the question).

Comment: Because of its position, it's going to be considered (by any program) as an argument to -c.  Your original question had all the paths at the end, and I provided a solution that would not only work for that, but also see any argument that wasn't preceded by an option switch as a path.  You cannot expect the program to somehow know what's a path and what isn't except, as in your original question, by whether or not there is an option involved.  Do you really have a situation my code will not work for or are you just trying anything to make it break?!

Comment: I have a real necessity for this, and this is why I asking here. If it were not a hard question I would have no need for asking. Situation is that paths will always come last, and that there are options with and without arguments. Just think on rsync: it has options with arguments like -e and options without like -a

Comment: Okay, in the example you give, how can we know that last Value after -F isn't a path, and that -F is an option that doesn't have any arguments?  You said above that you can't rely on there being a backslash in a path so how could a human, much less a batch file, know that?  You mention rsync but it knows that any parameter doesn't have a "loose" Value but rather of the -option=value syntax.  Anything not starting with a dash is a path, and the last one is the destination.  Your situation seems to be ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe you do not know rsync quite well? Options to rsync can be without arguments (-v equivalent to --verbose) or with arguments (-e COMMAND equivalent to --rsh=COMMAND). Yes, -e accepts a loose argument, not only the -option=value syntax. Same happens with Microsoft's forfiles which accepts [/s] and [/p PATH]. http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc753551(v=ws.10).aspx What you can rely on is in having the list of options of each type, since you program the script and know which ones are of each type. Those of forfiles are fine for an example.